# Map routes only for one controller and actions of this controller. Others routing settings leave operable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, t4mvc

First of all, I need to say that I'm using T4MVC. I have many custom routes in my `RouteConfig`. This is an example:

```
    routes.MapRoute("CollectionDetails", "collection/{slug}/{collectionId}", MVC.Collection.CollectionDetails());    
..............................................                     
    routes.MapRoute("Sales.Index", "sales", MVC.Sales.Index());
    routes.MapRoute("CustomPage", "custom/{slug}", MVC.CustomPage.Index());
```

All these routes are working fine. But I have one controller (AccountController) for which I need to map routes in such scheme: `ControllerName/ActionName/`. 
I mean that I have `Account Controller`. This controller has such `Actions`: `CreateAccount, CreateAccount(POST), ResetPassword, LogIn, etc...` I need to create such `Urls` for them: `Account/CreateAccount`, `Account/LogIn`. I wonder is it possible to resolve using one `route` in `RouteConfig`?

Comment: i don't think you need any extra route for accomplish your work , you can directly get those url through html helper
html.actionlink("create",account,new{id=model.id})
it will such kind of url what you want,id is optional if you want pass any id then you can use otherwise only two parameters are enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to lock a route to a specific Controller, (in your case, to just the Account Controller) then you can do it like this with T4MVC:

From T4MVC Documentation: [2.2.5 routes.MapRoute](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Documentation#225-routesmaproute-typically-in-globalasax)

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
     "Account",
     "Account/{action}/{id}",
      MVC.Account.Index(null));
```

otherwise you could also achieve the same thing with

from documentation [2.3. Use constants to refer to area, controller, action and parameter names](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Documentation#23-use-constants-to-refer-to-area-controller-action-and-parameter-names)

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Account",
     url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = MVC.Account.Name, action = MVC.Account.ActionNames.Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Or go back to the default way of doing it

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Account",
     url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This should satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Using default MVC route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index, id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

you should be able to achieve what you want..

So long as it is defined at the bottom of the list your customs routes will trigger before it and they will continue to work. When it comes to account URLs your custom routes will not match it and they will go with the default route to the account controller and the action specified inside the URL.

More about MVC routing http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: Updated answer to use T4MVC for default controller and action.